# "It seems to me" statements

Tags: phrase-requests

Could someone please advise whether the statements below are correct?

> Ŝajnas al mi, ke ni ĉiuj konsentas pri tio. (It seems to me that we all agree on this.)
>
> Ŝajnas al mi, ke tio estas nun klara. (It seems to me that this is now clear.)

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, those are correct. In English, the "it" is just a dummy that refers to the phrase with "that" in it. It's not necessary in Esperanto - just like you don't need an "it" in "it's raining" (*pluvas*).

The second sentence would be better with *tio*:

- *Ŝajnas al mi, ke **tio** estas nun klara*.

If you had a list of sentences and were talking about just one, you could use *tiu*.

In this context *ĉi* is not necessary. It's important to express ideas (as you have done) and not translate words. Just because someone expresses an idea with "this" in one context and "that" in another, doesn't mean that we need to fuss about *tio* vs *tio ĉi* when the context doesn't call for it.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, those are entirely correct! Note that generally *tio* makes more sense in the second sentence, but *tiu* is fine here as well and works better depending on the context.

By the way, ‘this’ would be *ĉi tio* or *tio ĉi* rather than just *tio*.

Comment: I'm voting this answer up, but do note that the last line ("By the way, ‘this’ would be ĉi tio or tio ĉi rather than just tio.") This kind of comment is a symptom of the problem of translating words rather than expressing ideas. There are countless contexts in English where "we agree on this" and "we agree on that" mean the same thing - and in Esperanto there's no actual need to express ***ĉi** tio* except to contrast with *tio*. If there is no simple *tio* to contrast with, then the *ĉi* is not required.

Comment: @TomasoAlexander You're absolutely right. I just put it there to go with the most direct translation, because I do not know the context of the original sentences and in some contexts the distinction might be relevant.